# Angular 2: Redirect on page load

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When my Angular 2 (v2.4) application loads I am trying to redirect the user to a certain page regardless of the URL they have entered. For example, if the user loads the app using `http://www.myapp.com/somepage` or `http://www.myapp.com/anotherpage` the app will automatically redirect to `http://www.myapp.com/entrypage`.

To this I have the following code in my AppComponent (which is the first component loaded):

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router) {


    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.router);
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/", { skipLocationChange: true });
    }


}
```

However when the app loads the redirect is not working. It appears to quickly redirect before going back to the original requested route.

How can I get this working? Is there a "correct" way to get this working?

JT

Comment: Try the below code.  this.router.navigate("/", { skipLocationChange: true });

Answer (score 2):

Use a wildcard in your route configuration. `path: **` will take any undefined url and route the user to a specific, defined route. You could do something like this:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: AppComponent,
}, {
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: ''
}];
```

Then, in `app.module.ts`, load your routes under the `imports` array: `RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set your application routes in app.routing.ts ? You can set default value for all urls there, regardless of the URL they have entered.